# Chrome push Notification

Tags: javascript, json, web, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

I am trying to build chrome push notification.
 I  tried to implement a random code which is referred from web.

The code goes as follows :

**notification.html**

```
<script>
    function shows(){

    var notify= webkitNotifications.createNotification('icon48.png','My notification',
    'hi buddy');    
    notify.show();
    }
    if(webkitNotifications){
        setInterval(function()
        {
            shows();
            }, 1000);
    }else{
    chrome.tabs.create({url : "error.html"})
    }

</script>
```

And in **error.htm**

> there is an error in your extension

In **manifest.JSON**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1",
    "description" : "Display every 5 sec",
    "icons" : {"48" :"icon48.png"},
    "permissions" : ["tabs","notifications"],
    "background": {"page": "notifications.html"}
}
```

The problem is Extension is getting loaded in chrome, but it doesn't respond to the code. Neither are the notification shown. :( please help.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used webkitNotifications however I achieved chrome notifications using chrome.notifications API's.
This is how I did it.

In your **background.js**,

Write a code which sends a message.

```
function updateValues(){
           var messageString = 'updated';
           chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                            body : messageString
                        });
}

updateValues();
setInterval(updateValues, 10000);
```

Add a listener now. outside the function which updates the values frequently.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {
    var message = msg.body;

    chrome.notifications.onClicked.removeListener(openTab);

    chrome.notifications.create(getNotificationId(), {
        title : 'Test Update Notification',
        iconUrl : 'notification.png',
        type : 'basic',
        message : message
    }, function(id) {
    });

    chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(openTab);
});

function openTab(notificationId) {
   var onClickLink = "http://www.mywebsitenotificationstest.com/";
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url : onClickLink
        });
    }

function getNotificationId() {
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9007199254740992) + 1;
    return id.toString();
}
```

That's it.

Basically, when the js is loaded

1. updateValues() API gets called and a listener is created to call
   updateValues for every 10sec.
2. Once updateValues is invoked, it
   sends a message to the runtime.onMessage listener using the
   sendMessage API.
3. Inside onMessage listener we've code to create
   notifications using chrome.notifications.create.

That's it.

Edit:
My code is much bigger, I copy pasted parts of it.

Comment: facing the same problem. what happens is i am not getting any kind of error but i dnt c any notification . i tried editing and implementing ur code..

Comment: @ChiragKamat
Save the script which I suggested as background.js and edit your manifest.json to

"background":{
   "scripts":["background.js"]
  }

This will load the script on start-up of plugin.

Comment: @ChiragKamat Did this solve your issue with notifications?